# How to create extension to Realm List?

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to create an extension to Realm List:

```
extension List {
    var toArray: Array<Any> {
        return Array(self)
    }
}
```

to write `media.toArray` instead of `Array(media)`. But in my example the result would be `Any`, so i got to do an additional cast. How to keep List generic type and write an extension, that would transform to array of same type as List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `List` is already a generic collection, you simply need to use its generic type, `Element` as the generic type parameter of `Array` in your `toArray` computed property.

```
extension List {
    var toArray: Array<Element> {
        return Array(self)
    }
}
```